# R : legend() error

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to generate a legend for a plot to show the colors' relationships to cluster # in a plot.  I don't actually need it in the plot I just want to generate a legend then copy and paste it into a powerpoint slide.

I found this code here that does what I want:

http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

```
# Legend Example
attach(mtcars)
boxplot(mpg~cyl, main="Milage by Car Weight",
    yaxt="n", xlab="Milage", horizontal=TRUE,
   col=terrain.colors(3))
legend("topright", inset=.05, title="Number of Cylinders",
    c("4","6","8"), fill=terrain.colors(3), horiz=TRUE)
```

but am having difficulty replicating it.  Here's my code:

```
plot(seq(1,7), seq(1,7), col = c(1:7))
legend("topright", inset = .05, title = "Cluster Colors"
    ,fill = c(1:7), horiz=T)
```

when I run it, I get this error:

```
Error in as.graphicsAnnot(legend) : 
  argument "legend" is missing, with no default
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, can you replace title with legend  and try again ?

Comment: @MamounBenghezal: What do you mean?

Comment: plot(seq(1,7), seq(1,7), col = c(1:7));
legend("topright", inset = .05, **legend** = "Cluster Colors"
    ,fill = c(1:7), horiz=T)

Comment: @MamounBenghezal: No luck - same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original plot has an argument "legend", it is just unnamed argument. As updated here:

```
legend("topright", inset=.05, title="Number of Cylinders",
   legend =c("4","6","8"), fill=terrain.colors(3), horiz=TRUE)
```

So, what you need is this.

```
plot(seq(1,7), seq(1,7), col = c(1:7))
legend("topright", inset = .05, title = "Cluster Colors",legend= c(1:7)
       ,fill = c(1:7), horiz=TRUE)
```

The `?` command, as in `?legend`, is useful to find out about these things.